# MySQL pooling within nodejs

Tags: mysql, node.js

Hi i've just read the docs of mysql package for nodejs. Lil bit not sure of how is the best practice to work with pooling.

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var pool  = mysql.createPool(...);

pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
  // Use the connection
  connection.query('SELECT something FROM sometable', function (error, results, fields) {
    // And done with the connection.
    connection.release();

    // Handle error after the release.
    if (error) throw error;

    // Don't use the connection here, it has been returned to the pool.
  });
});
```

Do we have to call release() method everytime we have performed query?

And one more.

What is the difference between using pool directly to perform the query vs. using getConnection method then perform the query?
Code using pool direcly:

```
var pool  = mysql.createPool(...);
pool.query(...)
```

Using getConnection method then perform the query:

```
pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
  connection.query(....);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you ask for getting a connection, you basically reserve that connection for a little while. This is important for 2 reasons:

1. Only 1 query can be done on a connection at a time, never in parallel. So this prevents 2 things from using the same connection.
2. Transactions are connection-based and all queries within the transaction *must* happen on that connection object.

The mysql library would have no way to predict that you are 'done' your transaction, this is why you need to release it.

Aside: You should consider looking into `mysql2` for a similar library that's more powerful, and use promises instead of this callback pattern.

**Update based on comment**

When you do `query` directly on the pool, the pool will automatically get the connection, run the query and release it for you.

This is useful if you just need to do a single query and don't care about transactions.

Comment: What is the difference between using the pool directly (var pool  = mysql.createPool(...);
pool.query(...)) vs. using getConnection() method then perform the query?

Comment: I updated my answer to answer that question as well.